# RTD #N/A error in Excel 365 only when RTD COM object is registered at the user level

Tags: excel, com, office365, excel-addins, rtd

I am developing a COM object that implements the excel RTD interface using .NET c#.  It is a **x64 bit project and office is also 64bit**.

The 64bit RTD COM object works just fine in Office 2016 (also 64bit).

I can register the COM object at the CURRENT user level and Office 2016 loads it just fine.  Machine level registry works just fine too.

However, when using office 365 64bit version.  I can only get it to work when registered at the HKLM level.

I would like to get it to work at the User level.  Not everyone in the organization using it may have admin rights to their machine.

Is there some way to get it to work?  Am I missing more registry settings or is there some policy that is blocking it at the user level?
**NOTE:  excel does recognize my COM object, but disables it.**   I cannot enable it at all.  This all feels like some policy restriction new to office 365.

Comment: I've been using COM a LONG time. I have never heard of what an RTD COM object is (or I don't recognize it now) and I don't want to Google it. Your question should at least once use the regular form and not the acronym. My experience with Office automation having had to program against it... Prefer to use late binding and dispatch interfaces and not the dual versions. Interfaces change and sometimes it seems they aren't always registered correctly. I'd recommend using procmon.exe to find out how registry is being searched during execution to find objects and interfaces for troubleshooting.

Comment: The question is about RTD COM Servers.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm getting N/A from my RTD server which worked fine on 2016...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't find the right hive in the windows registry for registering your RTD COM server on a machine with Office 365. See [Add-ins for Office programs may be registered under the \Wow6432Node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/user-interface/addins-are-registered-under-wow6432node) for possible routes.

I'd suggest investing your time for exploring capabilities of [Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/excel-rtd-servers.php) which allows creating installers for you. Also you may take a look at [ExcelDNA](https://excel-dna.net/).

Comment: Wow6432Node is for a 32 bit COM object  (ie. 32 bit office) on a 64 bit machine.  Both my COM object and office are 64 bits.  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\<application>\Addins.   This really seams to be an 365 issue.  As with office 2016 and prior, everything works just fine.